Razor Pages - .NET 8.0 - ModelBinding? - Entity Framework
I am so sorry to bother you guys, but I need help getting my information from Entity Framework. I do not know what I am missing.
I am working with Razor pages. I have run my page, I see all my values in the locals window. I see every field that I can image for my one order. So, that part I am not having an issue with.
The issue occurs when I return my page:
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
{
    string id = TempData["id"]?.ToString();

    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var x = await _context.dbTable.SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.order_id == id);

    if (x != null)
    {
        return Page();
    }
    
    return NotFound();
}

I see my temp data completely, but everything goes null in my model when the page gets returned. I can't even do a simple @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.id) to see if it gets displayed.
I am not asking for the solution, I just want to know what to look for. I have been googling YouTube, ChatGPT, and Gemini, and I am missing something.
If it helps, I can see my values in the ViewData if I look in Model.ViewData[0] then I open it up and I see the entire query that was technically returned. It's just the model that is turned to null.

According to your codes, your id and X all the method inside object which couldn't be accessed after the method excepted completely.
If you want to pass some value from the razor page model class to the razor view, you should firstly set the model object or property inside the class and then set the value for it.
For example, if you want to pass id to the razor view.
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
    //create the property to store the value 
    public string? id { get; set; }
    //create the property to store the value 
    public  Movie Movie { get; set; } = default!;
    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
         //set the value
        // id = TempData["id"]?.ToString();
        id = "test";
        //Movie = await _context.dbTable.SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.order_id == id);
        //set the value for testing
        Movie = new Movie { Id = 1, Name = "test1" };
        return Page();
    }
}

public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

Razor page:
id:
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.id)

<hr />

name :  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Movie.Name)

Result:

